# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when merging pandas datframes from BigQuery

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, google-bigquery

I created a BigQuery dataset from the open data Github data on BigQuery.

I am now bringing that data (two different tables) into pandas as dataframes, and it works fine. When I call 'type' on my join column, they both come up as pd.Series.

Here's my script:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'XXXXXXXXX.json')
project_id = 'XXXXXX'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials, project=project_id)

bqstorageclient = bigquery_storage_v1beta1.BigQueryStorageClient(
    credentials=credentials
)


language_query = """
  SELECT repo_name, Language, Bytes,
  CASE 
  when LOWER(Language) NOT IN ('javascript', 'python', 'ruby', 'java'
                        , 'php', 'c++', 'css', 'c#', 'go'
                        , 'c', 'typescript', 'shell', 'swift'
                        , 'scala', 'objective-c') then 'Other'
  else Language END AS language_category
  FROM github_project.langauges

  LIMIT 1000"""

language_query_dataframe = (
    client.query(language_query)
    .result()
    .to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient)
)

commit_query = """
    SELECT Commit, Author, DateSeconds, repo_name
    FROM github_project.commits
    LIMIT 1000
    """

commit_query_dataframe = (
    client.query(commit_query)
    .result()
    .to_dataframe(bqstorage_client=bqstorageclient)
)

merged_data = pd.merge(commit_query_dataframe, language_query_dataframe, on='repo_name')
```

That final line,

```py
merged_data = pd.merge(commit_query_dataframe, language_query_dataframe, on='repo_name')
```

throws the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Where is the array coming from? I can't find an answer or understand why merging on two Series should kick that out.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the shapes of `commit_query_dataframe` and `language_query_dataframe` ?

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam np.shape gives (1000,4) for both and type gives 'pandas.core.series.Series' for repo_name in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue-- it was on the BigQuery side. repo_name was an array in the BigQuery table and I missed it, so using UNNEST in my original query solved this issue.

Leaving up for anyone else that runs into this. Check and make sure your join column isn't of type 'Repeated' on BigQuery.

Comment: It's cool that you figured out. It's very helpful to leave an answer like this for others.